# How to filter subclass objects from superclass Set and add them to subclass List

Tags: java, collections

The Composite Design-Pattern with the following UML Class Diagram is given:

[image]

Class A is abstract and items is realized with a `HashSet<A>`.
I want to implement the getAllC() method of Class B, by iterating through the given `HashSet<A>`, check whether or not the current object is from type C and (if true) adding it to a `List<C>`.

My problem is that I can not come up with a proper idea of inserting the Class C - Objects to the new `List<C>`, since the given `HashSet<A>` has a different generic parameter.

My path of thought so far given in code (obviously not working, just wanted to show my initial "approach"):

```
public class B {

   private Set<A> items = new HashSet<A>();

   public List<C> getAllC() {

      List<C> c_list = new ArrayList<C>();

      for (A a : items) {
         if (a.getClass().equals(C.class)) {
            c_list.add(a);
         }
      }
      return c_list; 
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use `if (a instanceof C) { c_list.add((C) a); }` (casting) or if you’re using java 12 or later `if (a instanceof C c) { c_list.add(c); }`.

Comment: @BeUndead I believe it's from java 14 on

Comment: @fps you’re right, I can’t modify the comment now though. Not sure why I thought 12, I think my memory is just ‘after java 11’ and then conclusions were jumped to.

Comment: @BeUndead Yeah, we have ancient Java (pre 8), Java 8, Java 11, and all the modern, cool stuff that comes after 11 :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use streams, and it's simple as this:

```
items.stream()
     .filter(el -> el instanceof C) // consider only the one you want
     .map(el -> (C) el) // cast them
     .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect them
```

but if you want to keep your imperative version, you can just do this:

```
public class B {

   private Set<A> items = new HashSet<A>();

   public List<C> getAllC() {

      List<C> c_list = new ArrayList<C>();

      for (A a : items) {
         if (a instanceof C) { 
              c_list.add((C) a); 
         }
      }
      return c_list; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's what want to do:

1. Check if type is `a instanceof C`
2. Cast your object

```
public class B {

   private Set<A> items = new HashSet<A>();

   public List<C> getAllC() {

      List<C> c_list = new ArrayList<C>();

      for (A a : items) {
         // equals() is intended to compare two object. 
         // You want to know if the type is equals. This is done by using instanceof
         // if (a.getClass().equals(C.class)) {
         if (a instanceof C)
            c_list.add((C) a); // know you cast your object to its new type
         }
      }
      return c_list; 
   }
}
```